# Validation Rules and the REST API

Tags: visualforce, validation, rest

I'm testing the REST API using workbench on an object that has many validation rules. Why is is that the REST API only returns a single error, instead of an array? If this were in a normal visualforce page using a standard controller, visualforce displays all error messages. I am looking to replicate that in my application, without the need for Apex:Form or Apex:PageMessages.

I can't evaluate the rules on the Apex side, as they may be created after deployment.